# Reaching repeater item: The Logic

Tags: asp.net, repeater, findcontrol, asprepeater

Here is my design page:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mvProducts" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
  <asp:View runat="server" ID="mvProducts1">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptDiscount" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="divProduct1">
          <div class="divProductHeader">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlDiscount" runat="server" CssClass="divProductHeaderDiscount" Visible="true">
              <div class="menuTextTopSpacer"></div>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDiscount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("discount") %>'></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>`
```

I just want to reach `pnlDiscount` item but I dont know how.   I made a search but it just helped to increase my confusion.

Indeed, I want to learn the logic on finding a control in a repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your reapter then use [FindContol()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get to the `Panel`

```
protected void rptDiscount_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Panel myPanel= e.Item.FindControl("pnlDiscount") as Panel;

    //Do some work
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to do before databinding. But this seems easier. Thanks again...